# Vuetify Data Table: How are header filter functions applied

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

According to the Vuetify docs for [custom filters in v-data-table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#custom-filter), one can customize the filtering of a specific table column by supplying a **filter** property on header items.

In my application, I want to use this to customize filtering for a single column. For all other columns, I want to preserve the default string matching behavior.

As a jumping off point [(see codepen)](https://codepen.io/hloeding/pen/gOMrExa), I have supplied a custom filter, that just returns **true**:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data(){
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Car Manufacturers',
          value: 'car',
          filter(){ return true }
        },
        {
          text: 'Country of Origin',
          value: 'country'
        }
      ],
      items: [
        { car: 'Honda', country: 'Japan' },
        { car: 'Audi', country: 'Germany' },
        { car: 'Ford', country: 'USA' }
      ],
      search: ''
    }
  },
})
```

and

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-text-field
        label="Search"
        v-model="search"
      >
      </v-text-field>
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="items"
        :search="search"
      >
      </v-data-table>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

I would now have expected, that the filter on column **car** matches all rows and therefore the entire table is shown, no matter what search string I enter.

What I observe is, that the table is still filtered, but only by column **country**.

Conversely, when I change my filter to return **false**, an empty table is shown. I would then have expected, that the table is filtered only by column **country**.

How are the headers filters applied? Or, more precisely:

For each row, how are the results of the respective column filters combined to yield a filter result for the entire row?

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I found [this answer](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/11600#issuecomment-642273351) within a bug report on v-data-table filtering.

I still don't understand the thinking behind this, but apparently, custom column filters are handled differently than columns without custom filters:

Rows match, if (1) they match **every()** specified custom column filter and (2) they match **some()** default filter (i.e. contain search string).

The matching code in Vuetify seems to be [this](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/search?q=searchTableItems):

```
  return items.filter(item => {
    // Headers with custom filters are evaluated whether or not a search term has been provided.
    // We need to match every filter to be included in the results.
    const matchesColumnFilters = headersWithCustomFilters.every(filterFn(item, search, defaultFilter))

    // Headers without custom filters are only filtered by the `search` property if it is defined.
    // We only need a single column to match the search term to be included in the results.
    const matchesSearchTerm = !search || headersWithoutCustomFilters.some(filterFn(item, search, customFilter))

    return matchesColumnFilters && matchesSearchTerm
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but for those who still have the problem, I had to add `filter-mode="union"` to my data table

```
const headers = [
  {
    key: 'lastName',
    title: 'lastName',
    filter: (value: string, query: string) => {
      const normalizedValue = normalizeString(value.toString())
      const normalizedQuery = normalizeString(query.toString())

      return normalizedValue.toLowerCase().includes(normalizedQuery.toLowerCase())
    },
  },
]


 <VDataTable
  :sort-by="sortBy"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  ...
  :search="search"
  filter-mode="union"
 <VDataTable
```

With this, my search works in addition to the specific filter on my column.